# convert csv to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to read simple csv to pandas, actual problem is that it doesnt separate ",".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\xxx\\1.csv', header=0, delimiter ="\t")
print(df)
```

I have tried sep=',' and it does not separate..

```
Event," 2016-02-01","   2016-02-02","   2016-02-03","   2016-02-04","   
Contact joined,"5","7","18","20",
Launch first time,"30","62","86","110",
```

It should looks like 1 header with Dates and 2 rows:

```
  2016-02-01    2016-02-02   etc
0          5             7
1         30            62
```

UPDATE: Yes, the problem was in cdv itself with unnecessary quotes and characters.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your csv?

Comment: " Event,"" 2016-02-01"","" 2016-02-02"","" 2016-02-03"",""

Comment: Please edit in your post and just copy/paste a few lines of your csv (and just delete the rest of the row after the first few columns if it are a lot of them). It seems like your csv is formatted incorrectly, with a lot of unnecessary `"`.

Comment: @NielsHenkens yes, formatting of csv was incorrect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using both `delimiter=` and `sep=`, which both do the same thing. If it is actually comma seperated, try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\xxx\\1.csv')
print(df)
```

`sep=','` is the default, so it's not necessary to explicitly state that. The same goes for `header=0`. `delimiter=` is just an alias for `sep=`.

You still seem to have a problem with the formating of your column names. If you post an example of your csv, I can try to fix that...